# bundle isomorphism

Tags: differential-geometry, mathematical-physics

Let $M$ be a manifold and let $U_{\alpha}$ and $U_{\beta}$  be coordinate charts with
coordinates $x^{\alpha}$ and $x^{\beta}$, respectively.

> How to show that $f_{\alpha} : U_{\alpha}\times\mathbb{R}^n\to TM_{|U_{\alpha}}$,
>   $(p,a^{\alpha})\to\sum_{i} a^\alpha_i\frac{\partial}{\partial x^\alpha_i}|_{p}$
>   is a bundle isomorphism?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What is the relation of $U_\beta$? With what are you having trouble?

Answer (score 1):

Checking that $f_{\alpha}$ is a bundle isomorphism is the same as checking two things

- $f_{\alpha}$ is a diffeomorphism ;
- $f_{\alpha}$ commutes with the projection maps $\pi_{\alpha} : \mathrm{U}_{\alpha} \times \mathbb R^n \to \mathrm{U}_{\alpha}$ and $\pi'_{\alpha} : \mathrm{TM}_{|\mathrm U_{\alpha}} \to \mathrm{U}_{\alpha}$ i.e you have to check that $f_{\alpha} \circ \pi_{\alpha} = \pi'_{\alpha} \circ f_{\alpha}$.

By definition of the tangent bundle $$\mathrm{TM}_{|\mathrm U_\alpha} = \bigcup_{x \in \mathrm U_{\alpha}} \{x\} \times \mathbb R^n$$

We deduce that $f_{\alpha}$ is a diffeomorphism. The only thing left to check is the compatibility with the projection maps. But this comes immediately.

Hence $f_{\alpha}$ is a bundle isomorphism.